# How to delete record in iPhone address book using CONTACTS Framework ios 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to delete contact from phone contact from my app, as this ABAddressBookRemoveRecord method is deprecated in i os 9. so now how can i delete contact.
Is there any method in contacts framework??

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: without giving answer why down vote??

Comment: Down votes without any reason is rather common here, just get used to it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete AddressBook Framework was deprecated in iOS9, you should check out the Contacts Framework instead:
[Contacts Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328)

A nice tutorial explaining deleting records [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ios-9-swift/9781491936689/ch04.html).

The tutorial covers Swift, but the same principle applys to Objective-C as well.

Comment: i have revised this framework, but i dont get anything from this.

Comment: sure.. here -> https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ios-9-swift/9781491936689/ch04.html#recipe-deleting-contacts.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code if you want to delete all contacts in one go using CNContacts

```
- (void) deleteAllContacts {
    CNContactStore *contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES) {
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey];
            NSString *containerId = contactStore.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [contactStore unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
            } else {
                CNSaveRequest *saveRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];

                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                    [saveRequest deleteContact:[contact mutableCopy]];
                }

                [contactStore executeSaveRequest:saveRequest error:nil];
                DDLogVerbose(@"Deleted contacts %lu", cnContacts.count);
            }
        }
    }];

}
```